# Why does the pytorch crossEntropyLoss use label encoding, instead of one-hot encoding?

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I'm learning on CrossEntropyLoss module in pytorch.
And the tutor says, you should input target value y with 'label encoded', not 'one-hot encoded'.
Like this

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
Y = torch.tensor([0])
Y_pred_good = torch.tensor([[2.0, 1.0, 0.1]])  
Y_pred_bad = torch.tensor([[0.5, 1.0, 0.3]])

l1 = loss(Y_pred_good, Y)
l2 = loss(Y_pred_bad, Y)

print(l1.item())
print(l2.item())
```

But I learned that CrossEntropy Loss is caculated with one-hot encoded class information.
Does the pytorch module transform label encoded into one-hot encoded? or is there another way to caculate CELoss with label encoded information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between the multi-label CE loss, [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), and the binary version, [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html).

For the binary case, the implemented loss allows for "soft labels" and thus requires the binary targets to be floats in the range `[0, 1]`.
In contrast, [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) works with "hard" labels, and thus does not need to encode them in a one-hot fashion.

If you do the math for the multi-class cross-entropy loss, you'll see that it is inefficient to have a one-hot representation for the targets. The loss is `-log p_i` where `i` is the true label. One only need to index the proper entry in the predicted probabilities vector. This can be done via multiplication be the one-hot encoded targets, but it is much more efficient to do it be indexing the right entry.

---

Note: It seems like recent versions of [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) also support one-hot encoded targets ("smooth labels").